# Flutter conditional statement with Card(color:)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to change the color below from red to green if the value of a variable is more than 10. How would I do that? as 'color:' does not accept if, else statements:

```
         Card( 
            child: Column(
              children:[
                Text('Calls Taken',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),),
                Text('10'),
              ],
            ),
            color: Colors.redAccent

          ),
```

The above card widget is under a class that inherits StatelfulWidgets

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried exporting your logic to a function that returns Colors type?

Answer (score 18):

Just use a ternary if

```
color: variable > 10 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.green
```

Comment: can you do this with more than one condition? i.e. an else if statement

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners `color: (variable1 > 10 && s == "foo") ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.green`. If you want more complicated if/else combinations you can still do this. You can even nest these if/else, but they become hard to read. In this case I strongly suggest to move the code to a method instead.