# How to pass values between different flutter pages, and use it in everypart of the code?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

```
/this is slider from settings

value: sliderValue ??= 125,
label: sliderValue.toString(),
divisions: 23,
onChanged: (newValue) {
setState(
() => sliderValue = newValue,
);

                          },

//this is container in homepage
 Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.858,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
```

how can i change the color of container, and secondary color of the app  based on slider value?

Comment: Check the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100993/flutter-conditional-statement-with-cardcolor

Comment: Hope that solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the state managements methods for variable passing between pages like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc).

More beginner and easy way for this is passing a variable to the widget you need to use with that variable.

For example:

```
class ProjectPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? variable_one;
  final int? variable_two;

  const ProjectPage({super.key, this.variable_one, this.variable_two});

  @override
  _ProjectPageState createState() => _ProjectPageState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Provider Package to create a global variable which can be accessible from anywhere in the code